# improve the project of binary classification with categorical features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data

Here is a interview task of training a binary classification model. I will not show the detail of training data as the confidential issue. The variable $X$ has ten features and all the features are categorical value. Let's ignore the actual meaning of the data and just regard as a general binary classification problem with categorical features. Could you give me a few suggestions based on my answers and interviewee's feedback? `Pls note that it is a 3 hours online task, we will not consider the tools which is too complicate.`

*My answer:*

**Principle:**

1. The features of sample are almost categorical. Therefore we use `Greedy Target Statistics(TS)` to numeric the categorical features. For the category i of a feature, we use
   $$\text{TS = (count(cat = i && label=1) + a*p )/(count(cat = i) + a)}$$
   here a is the given hyper-parameter and
   $$\text{p = count(label=1)/(number of samples),}$$
   the global mean. (a,p) is used to smooth the value to avoid the trivial case (see Greedy TS)
2. Use logistic regress as learner

**The process of training is:**

1. Manually select features：discard columns 'Date' (no information), 'Product' (covered by 'Sub product'), 'Zipcode' (too many categories, may lead overfitting)
2. Use TS to numeric feature
3. Data processing:

   a) discard feature below 1 std

   b) max-min standardization

   c) Use tree model for feature selection
4. Training a logistic regression

*Interviewee's feedback associate with my understanding:*

1. **No exploratory data analysis or cross validation:** does that mean I need to show the statistics of raw data? like mean, std, correlation between features, e.t.c
2. **Feature selection and visualization was not in line with what we would expect from a candidate:**  We should print the scores of features based on the feature selection model?
3. **No optimization:** the optimization of hyper-parameter like value of a and choice of learner？

Let's ignore the weakness of `Greek TS`. I am not sure my understanding is correct and what should I do properly based on interviewee's feedback.

Tell me the information you need and I will update if I can.